# Efficient sampling in R (replacing loop with apply or similarly fast solution when sampling for a simulation)

Tags: r, apply, simulation, sampling

I have a dataframe of three columns: "x", "y", "measurement". An example is below.

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

set.seed(1)
df$measurement <- round(rnorm(nrow(df)),2)

head(df, n = 10)
```

I would like to draw a sample from this dataframe based on x values stored in *x*. Each sample size for the sampling *x* step should be  *n_sample*.

In other words, indexes are stored in *x* in the original dataframe. I will first sample *x* and then use these values to draw rows from *df*. This procedure needs to be repeated *n_sim* times.

I can achieve this using a loop, but it is painfully slow and inefficient in R. I would like to use *apply* kind of a function or a similarly faster way.

```
# number of simulation
n_sim  <- 20 

# sample using x values (indexes)
x_vals <- unique(df$x)

# size of each sample 
n_sample <- 3

# sampling
sample_xs <- replicate(n = n_sim, 
                       sample(x_vals, n_sample, replace = F), 
                       simplify = F)

# ***** SLOW R LOOP: NEEDS TO BE REPLACED ******
output_sampled <- list()
for(i in 1:n_sim){
  output_sampled[[i]] <- df[df$x %in% sample_xs[[i]], ]
}
```

An example sample is below:

```
output_sampled[[1]]
```

In the example above, x values 1, 4, 5 is selected in the sampling process, along with their pairings with all possible y values and the corresponding measurement. This gives us 15 pairings (there are 5 distinct y values and we sampled 3 x values, giving 3 * 5 = 15).

```
nrow(output_sampled[[1]])
```

How to replace the inefficient loop with something fast in R?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is faster (you can time them) but a one-liner is (after your code which I will not repeat)

```r
output_sampled2 <- with(df, lapply(sample_xs, \(s) df[x %in% s, ] )
```

using `lapply` for the loop, `with` for clarity (so that the clumsy `df$x` is unneeded) and the new notation `\(s)` for anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a 3x speedup (likely more for larger datasets) by using row indexing after sorting `df` and skipping `sample_xs` altogether:

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
set.seed(1)
df$measurement <- round(rnorm(nrow(df)),2)
n_sim  <- 20
df <- df[order(df$x),]
nx <- length(unique(df$x))
# get the starting point and length of each unique x value
lens <- rle(df$x)$lengths
idx <- cumsum(c(1L, lens))
n_sample <- 3L

output_sampled <- replicate(
  n_sim,
  df[sequence(lens[i <- sample(nx, n_sample)], idx[i]),],
  FALSE
)
```

Benchmarking against the original solution:

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
set.seed(1)
df$measurement <- round(rnorm(nrow(df)),2)
n_sim  <- 20

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  original = {
    x_vals <- unique(df$x)
    n_sample <- 3
    sample_xs <- replicate(n = n_sim, 
                           sample(x_vals, n_sample), 
                           simplify = F)
    output_sampled <- list()
    for(i in 1:n_sim){
      output_sampled[[i]] <- df[df$x %in% sample_xs[[i]], ]
    }
  },
  new = {
    df <- df[order(df$x),]
    nx <- length(unique(df$x))
    lens <- rle(df$x)$lengths
    idx <- cumsum(c(1L, lens))
    n_sample <- 3L
    
    output_sampled <- replicate(
      n_sim,
      df[sequence(lens[i <- sample(nx, n_sample)], idx[i]),],
      FALSE
    )
  }
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
#>  original 2228.701 2357.201 2744.9590 2426.401 2669.6005 7165.102   100
#>       new  605.900  670.151  801.9131  700.151  843.9015 2393.701   100
```